# Unable to broadcast multiple messages on socket io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm writing a program where I want to broadcast messages using socket IO. This is for a chat interface.

Here is my code

```
socket.on('send-chatMessage', message => {
        var gotNewMsg = false;
        sendChatMessage(message, chatMessagesJSON, function (resp, err) {
            console.log('resp from send chat --->');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
            console.log('err');
            console.log(err);
            gotNewMsg = true;
            socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', {
                message: message,
                name: users[socket.id]
            });
            if (gotNewMsg) {
                buildChatResponse(chatMessagesJSON, function (resp, err) {
                    console.log('resp from send chat');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
                    console.log('err');
                    console.log(err);
                    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', {
                        message: JSON.stringify(resp.messages[0].type),
                        name: 'Agent'
                    });
                });
            }
        })
    });
```

Here My first

```
socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', {
                message: message,
                name: users[socket.id]
            });
```

is working fine but my second one

```
if (gotNewMsg) {
                buildChatResponse(chatMessagesJSON, function (resp, err) {
                    console.log('resp from send chat');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
                    console.log('err');
                    console.log(err);
                    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', {
                        message: JSON.stringify(resp.messages[0].type),
                        name: 'Agent'
                    });
                });
            }
```

is not working as expected. I'm able to enter the `if` and also print the result. The only thing failing is broadcasting.

Here is my broadcast handlers.

```
socket.on('chat-message', data => {
    appendMessage(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`);
})
function appendMessage(message) {
    const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
    messageElement.innerText = message;
    messageContainer.append(messageElement);
};
```

please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Could you please provide a testable and runnable environment? (https://codesandbox.io/ or something like it)

Comment: Hey @Lwo, unfortunately there are a couple of security keys included, else I would had created a fiddle

Comment: Cant you omit those parts?